# Swift 2.0 POST Body null

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

Using a packet analyzer, I'm getting that my HTTP body is null. Is there any reason why my params aren't getting sent in the POST request?

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"SERVERURL")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    do {
        let params = ["returnInt":"5"] as Dictionary<String,String>
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    } catch {
        //Do nothing
    }
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("\(responseString)")
    }
    task!.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I saw with `println()` in the Playground, the `request.HTTPBody` is not *nil*. Also, my analyzer shows not *nil* either:

[image]